# CSS3 transforms cause screen flickering or aliased font

Tags: javascript, fonts, css, webkit

I am trying to apply some CSS3 transformations on elements and there is two problems.
The webpage contains lots of sticky notes and I want to zoom on click (scale) or flip on hover (rotateY) them by applying CSS classes with some JavaScript.

For example the zoom class is like this :

```
.postit-container.enabled {
  z-index: 15;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

For the flip effect I only use `rotateY(180deg)` on `:hover`.

Every stickies has a default rotation of 6deg applied and I fake random rotation with the `nth-child` CSS3 selector to apply different rotations.

Problem is that the screen flickers randomly when zooming or flipping **and** some fonts on the page are altered and looks ugly but not all of them, that's really weird.

Here is a jsfiddle so you can see the problem yourself :

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaPsn/10/)  (tested with Google Chrome 12.0.742.122 on Mac OS X 10.6.8)

I already tried the `-webkit-backface-visibility` trick, the flicker is gone on aminations and transforms for sure **but** fonts look ugly **all the time**.

I hope someone has a magic trick, because I really don't understand this behavior.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Could you put examples into a jsfiddle, the screenshots do not do a good job of illustrating the problem.

However I have experienced a similar problem, I couldn't find the cause of the problem either. Or come up with an explanation as to what might be happening.

However I did find a solution that worked in my case.

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

I applied it on all the elements that seemed to have rendering issues. In my case some elements that where not being transitioned or even in the same container, where being effected in a seemingly random and inconsistent manner.

something like.

```
.header *, .sticky * {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

I would love provide an explanation as to what preserve-3d does, however I found the documentation pretty ambiguous.

About the crux of what I gathered is that it may fix the problem ( which it did ) and it has two properties

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
//and
-webkit-transform-style: flat;
```

Flat is used by default.

Sorry I could not give a more detailed answer, but I hope this fixes the problem for you.

If anyone working on webKit is around, can you provide and explanation as to what this really does.

Comment: I would love to put examples into jsfiddle but this is a really complex page and a private project that I cannot share like that. I have tried your solution but does not seems to work ... :/ I'll see if I can fake it into jsfiddle ;) Thank you.

Comment: I took a look at and I fixed it using the method I mentioned in the answer. However I added the `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d` to the `.postit-container`. The only thing is the fonts a slightly blurry all the time, but they are at least consistent. If you are still getting issues with other elements. Try a blanket `* { -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; }`. Fiddle with changes here http://jsfiddle.net/AshMokhberi/sczCa/. I don't think your going to get it much better than this to be honest.  
Please don't forget to tick my answer.

Comment: The blur on the font is a major problem for me, but thank you anyway. :)

Comment: I think this is an overall rendering issue caused by the browser when it applies CSS3 transforms. I don't think you can find a work around, to the blurry text. It's either blurry all the time, or blurry during animations. Have you tried using a non custom font, do you get the same behaviour ?

Answer (score 10):

Try to add the following to your CSS:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

this will force Hardware Acceleration for chrome, since chrome often decides to not use it based on the CSS

Comment: I am sorry but this seems to have the same effect as `backface-visibility`. Fonts just look aliased all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. 
Found solution very long time, but finally I found it.

Just add class `.no-flickr` to any problem object on your site and you see correct animation without any bugs.

See this http://jsfiddle.net/DaPsn/92/

```
.no-flickr {        
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your text is just antialiased. Try to add 3d transform for example `rotateZ(0)` to fix that.